# Android, white screen is display when navigating between activities

Tags: java, android

The problem I have is that I have a white screen displayed when I want to switch between the 1st activity "ww1" and the 2nd activity "ww2", I have already tried a solution which says that I should create a theme in my styles.xml and add it to my second activity but the result was a black screen displayed while switching between the activity .

Here's the ww1.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/ww1"
   tools:context=".ww1">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="163dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/menu"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_btn"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
    android:background="@drawable/next"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

ww2.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/ww2"
  tools:context=".ww2">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="163dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/menu"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_btn"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/previous_btn"
    android:background="@drawable/next"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/previous_btn"
    android:layout_width="57dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="211dp"
    android:background="@drawable/previous"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Code used to display the ww2.xml :

```
            Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent(ww1.this, ww2.class);

            startActivity(mySuperIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right,R.anim.slide_to_left);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use it its worked for me

```
        Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent(ww1.this, ww2.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(mySuperIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right,R.anim.slide_to_left);
```

if dont work use it 
in Your style add

```
          <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
          <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
          </style>
```

However a better approach is do less things on main thread during Activity.onCreate and let show the preview screen while user is waiting. For a smooth transition, you can set a custom background to your windows adding this to your theme:

```
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/slash_screen</item>
     </style>
```

Comment: None of this suggestion worked for me I still got that black screen